Custom AuthenticationFilter and using permitAll function in spring boot
I am learning spring boot security architecture and for me best way to learn is to try to see how much can I customise it.
Right now I have problem with understanding how to make custom authentication filter.
Let say I have
@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain generalFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter generalFilterChainForAllApiRequests = jwtTokenAuthenticationFilter();
    generalFilterChainForAllApiRequests.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);

    return http.securityMatcher("/api/v1/**")
            .csrf(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(r -> {
                r.requestMatchers(
                        new RegexRequestMatcher("/api/v1/test/hola", null)).permitAll();
            })
            .addFilterAfter(generalFilterChainForAllApiRequests,UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
}



public JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter jwtTokenAuthenticationFilter() {
    JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(APPLICATION_GENERAL_PATH);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    return filter;
}

I understand that my JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter must not be Bean, otherwise it will be applied to all SecurityFilterChains, but I only want to use it on this one 'generalFilterChain'.
My problem is that I have added that my /api/v1/test/hola is permitted. As I understand it my custom filter should not be called, but it is and this end point is unauthorised.
What I am doing wrong, conceptually and is it possible to have this kinda solution, to have custom filter that can be applied to some end points

The customized filter should be invoked since permitAll() is checked as the final step in the security chain. However, I think access to /api/v1/test/hola should be permitted.
